# Git API to access a remote repository without cloning it

Tags: git, github, jgit

I need to access a Git remote repository to get the commit history (and just that) through a Java application. JGit, I see, is an option. From its documentation, I learned you have to clone the repository to access it.

Is there a way to access the repository remotely (i.e, without cloning it), with JGit or a different API?

As I'm interested in getting only the commit history, I don't see a point in cloning the repository and fetching the updates every time I need to see the latest commit history.

Any pointers is appreciated.

Comment: Probably looking out for something at https://developer.github.com/v3/

Comment: The commit history *is* the repository. Do you mean just the commit log messages, dates, and times like the output of `git log`? You're probably better off just cloning the repository, it will be faster than trying to get it via a web API, and you don't have to manage updates.

Comment: i think git ls-remote is one of the few commands in which you don't need to clone, but it doesn't bring you the commits

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Comment: Thanks you Rudiger for pointing that out. I did get some idea from the answers. Marking the closest answer that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As [Schwern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14660/schwern) pointed out, the commit history *is* the repository.

The sensible way to walk the history of a Git repository is to clone it first. If you are interested in the history only, you can omit the checkout or create a bare clone. In JGit, use the `CloneCommand` like this:

```java
Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
  .setURI("https://example.org/repo.git")
  .setDirectory("/path/to/local/copy")
  .setNoCheckout(true) // or .setBare(true)
  .call();
```

See this article for more details on JGit's CloneCommand: http://www.codeaffine.com/2015/11/30/jgit-clone-repository/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/), but it's much faster and easier to just clone the repository.

Specifically you'd [get all references](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#get-all-references) and filter for branches (`refs/heads/...`). Then [get the latest commit on each branch](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#get-a-commit) and then fetch its parents, and its parents's parents, and so on until you reach the root of the repository.

Keep in mind a commit can have multiple parents, so you can't just store the commits linearly, you need to build a graph.

And fetching each commit is a separate web request.

And you're [rate limited to 5000 requests per hour](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting).

To get updates, repeat the process until you reach a commit you've seen before. This means you're gonna have to store the commit info somewhere, at least the commits you've seen. It's not sufficient to store just the IDs of the branch heads because a rebase might change them.

---

Or you can do a bare clone, `git clone --bare`, to get the repository without a checkout, that will save a good chunk of disk space (but not network). Then use the normal Git procedures to examine history.

The Git repository format is extremely efficient, often the complete history is no larger than the current checkout size. Its network protocols are also very, very efficient. And it knows how to update itself with just a `git fetch origin`.

---

Or, if you just want a quick look by eye, use the `Commits` tab on the project's Github page. [For example](https://github.com/schwern/adventofcode2016/commits/master).

Comment: Thanks Schwern for posting that. The Java implementation of the Github API seems like an easy way of doing this.